# Template not being updated

Tags: jquery, handlebars.js

I'm trying to understand the handlebar template but i fail to see why my template is not being updated? the `jquery.js` and `handlebars-v2.0.0.js.js` are being  loaded successfully. There is no output at the console.

```js
<body>

<ul class="tweets"></ul>
  
<script id="entry-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  <li>
      <p><h2>{{author}}</h2></p>
      <p>{{tweet}}</p>
   </li>
</script>

   
   <script type="text/javascript" src="handlebars-v2.0.0.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>

   <script>
    
  (function () {
       var data = {
        author: 'Alex apple',
        tweet: '30 Days to learn jQuery'
       };
          var source = $('#entry-template').html();
          var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
          var temp = template(data);

          console.log(temp);
       
      })();
   </script>


 
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you have forgotten to actually call an anonymous function:

```
(function(){
  // the rest of the code skipped
})(); // note the parens
```

As it stands, you just define a function, but do not execute it. Note that the block should be placed after jquery and handlebars loaders - otherwise both `$` and `Handlebars` will be undefined.

Comment: i corrected it but there is still no output on the console!?

Comment: Are you sure you've made all the corrections? Works fine in the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zvfmjf3L/).